# Instancing PointCloud(ParticleCloud) in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

i am just a beginner in Threejs so please excuse if its a noobie question. but i haven't worked with particles.

How do i put points(particles) inside a custom geometry of a text geometry?
What i want to achieve is instance points inside a geometry or text then explode it to the world position. if someone direct me to the path, would be much helpful.

i know there's an example https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_points_dynamic 
but i cant understand whats happening in the render loop.

Comment: Have you tried to code something already?

Comment: right now i just have a text mesh i cant figure out how to push particles inside that mesh

Comment: it would be better, if you show your code, or, even better, if you have a jsfiddle or codepen or jsbin example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the ultimate solution, but just a starting point.

You can set points from any type of geometry (usual geometry or buffer geometry).

[image]

Let's imagine that you have a `THREE.TextGeometry()`, then you can set points from it as:

```
textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry("ABC", {
    font: font,
    size: 2,
    height: 0.25,
    curveSegments: 1,
    bevelEnabled: false
  });
  textGeo.computeBoundingBox();
  textGeo.computeVertexNormals();
  textGeo.center();

  fillWithPoints(textGeo, 1000); // fill our text geometry with 1000 random points

  textGeo.vertices.forEach(function(vertex){
    vertex.startPoint = vertex.clone(); // remember the starting position of a vertex
    vertex.direction = vertex.clone().normalize(); // set direction
  })
  textPoints = new THREE.Points(textGeo, new THREE.PointsMaterial({color: 0x00ff00, size: 0.1})); // all you need is to have a geometry and THREE.PointsMaterial()
  scene.add(textPoints);
```

To determine if a random point is inside our geometry, we can do the trick with projection of all the faces of our text geometry into 2D (x,y) and check if the point (with its x,y coordinates) is inside of one of projected triangles (faces):

```
function isPointInside(point, geometry) {
  var retVal = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i++) { //loop through faces
    face = geometry.faces[i];
    a = geometry.vertices[face.a];
    b = geometry.vertices[face.b];
    c = geometry.vertices[face.c];
    if (ptInTriangle(point, a, b, c)) {
      var retVal = true;
      break; // exit the loop if the point is in a projected triangle
    }
  }
  return retVal;
}
```

where

```
function ptInTriangle(p, p0, p1, p2) {
    // credits: http://jsfiddle.net/PerroAZUL/zdaY8/1/
    var A = 1/2 * (-p1.y * p2.x + p0.y * (-p1.x + p2.x) + p0.x * (p1.y - p2.y) + p1.x * p2.y);
    var sign = A < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    var s = (p0.y * p2.x - p0.x * p2.y + (p2.y - p0.y) * p.x + (p0.x - p2.x) * p.y) * sign;
    var t = (p0.x * p1.y - p0.y * p1.x + (p0.y - p1.y) * p.x + (p1.x - p0.x) * p.y) * sign;

    return s > 0 && t > 0 && (s + t) < 2 * A * sign;
}
```

and then in the animation loop we'll use the stuff of a vertex (startPoint and direction):

```
textGeo.vertices.forEach(function(vertex){
    vertex.copy(vertex.startPoint).addScaledVector(vertex.direction, 5 + Math.sin(Date.now() * 0.001) * 5);
});
textGeo.verticesNeedUpdate = true; // this is the most important thing, you have to set it to true after each rendering
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/sgvr37t0/) example

Comment: see points are on the vertices of text geo. what i want is inside the geometry.

Comment: here's a codepen it puts the points inside a cube, how do i get the positions from text?             https://codepen.io/artndes9/pen/QpMYpg

Comment: just a quick question, why are we adding "textgeo" to to pointcloud? can i add buffergeometry to store its attributes?

Comment: yes, you can create an instance of a buffer geometry, add random points (as attributes) to it and apply this geometry to the point cloud.

Comment: i did thanks, but when i animate the points few points appear from a cube i have no idea why... if you can tell me the problem would be helpful - [codepen](http://codepen.io/artndes9/pen/XMeBBr)

Comment: nevermind i  got it, had problem with storing values in float32buffer.